# Multiply raster by Numpy derived float value

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, raster-calculator, numpy

So I have a python script that uses numpy to calculate the mean of a field, then I try to use that mean value in a raster multiplication as follows:

```
na = arcpy.da.TableToNumPyArray("%SCRATCHWORKSPACE%\\rc_instruments_sr_noNULL2", "ratio")
    dMeanRatio = numpy.mean(na["ratio"])
    outCorrectedSR = Raster(outSimulated) * dMeanRatio
```

This gives an error of:

```
TypeError: expected a raster or layer name
```

This error is not referring to "Raster(outSimulated)" because I've replaced dMeanRatio with a hard-coded value and the script runs just fine. So my question is, how do I convert the dMeanRatio into a value that is acceptable to the raster multiplication?

Comment: I should clarify that dMeanRatio is being calculated correctly.

Comment: What do you get when you run `type(dMeanRatio)` in Python?

Comment: <type 'numpy.float32'>

Comment: Have you tried `float(dMeanRatio)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it figured out! Thanks to @Aaron's comments I was able to find a conversion:

```
dMeanRatio2 = numpy.asscalar(dMeanRatio)
```